# JSF FacesConverter ELResolver.getValue returns null

Tags: jsf, nullpointerexception, converters

I am trying to use a converter for an input form where I use some "selectOneMenu" components.

When I try to obtain my controller object inside converter's "getAsObject" method using:

```
facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver().
                getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, "usersController");
```

I get always null.
This is my converter class which is nested inside UserController class.

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = User.class, value="userConverter")
public static class UsersControllerConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        UserController controller = (UserController) facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver().
                getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, "usersController");
        System.out.println(value);
        System.out.println(getKey(value));
        System.out.println(controller);
        return controller.getUsers(getKey(value));
    }

    java.lang.String getKey(String value) {
        java.lang.String key;
        key = value;
        return key;
    }

    String getStringKey(java.lang.String value) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(value);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object object) {
        if (object == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (object instanceof User) {
            User o = (User) object;
            return getStringKey(o.getUsername());
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("object " + object + " is of type " + object.getClass().getName() + "; expected type: " + User.class.getName());
        }
    }

}
```

UserController class declaration:

```
@Named("userController")
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserController implements Serializable{
```

PS: I am a newbie, I just started learning Java EE/Faces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This,

```
UserController controller = (UserController) facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver().
    getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, "usersController");
```

is indeed not the right way. The following is the right way:

```
UserController controller = facesContext.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(
    facesContext, "#{usersController}", UsersController.class);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I looked over "Application" class and saw this method documentation now. That code was some NetBeans generated code for the controller. I will try to understand what is the difference.

Comment: You're welcome. The problem is that it only returns existing instance and don't precreate for you if it doesn't exist yet.